# Way to include pom.xml with runtime dependencies within a gradle built and published jar

Tags: gradle

Is there a simple way to have gradle automatically generated a pom file listing the jar dependencies (both to published jars of other sibling projects and external) and have it included in the jar and published to a maven repo?

There is a lot of documentation on this subject but I am either missing something or it is as complicated as it seems. Can this not be done automatically?

Comment: Yes it can be done automatically. For example with `bintray` plugin https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin which deploys to jcenter. Or with gradle `maven-publish` plugin http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html

Comment: I was looking at maven publish but something always escaped. Is there a comprehensive example somewhere, not little bits and pieces as in gradle docs?

Comment: Just search for maven-publish on github: https://github.com/duminghui/MavenPublishDemo/blob/master/mavenpublishdemo/android-maven-publish.gradle